# How do I update content in PPT textbox while not changing the format

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

Hey I am doing a reporting generate program.

I need to update certain part of some TextBox in PowerPoint (such as date).

I tried to do it with vba, but it turns out to be very complicated because once I updated the text content, I would have to re-setup all the format.

Is there an convenient  way to update certain part of the TextBox without have to re-setting up all the formatting?

Comment: You'll need to describe what you're doing more thoroughly. For example, how exactly are you finding the part of the text box that you want to update?

Comment: To find the textbox, you can navigate you powerpoint object to presentations->Item(i)->slides->item(i)->shapes->item(i)->textfram2->textrange. Don't know if that answers your question.... However, I found a replace method that I may be able to use.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the Replace method will do what you want.

Example:

```
Sub ReplaceText(oRng As TextRange, sReplaceWhat As String, sWithWhat As String)
    With oRng
        .Characters.Replace sReplaceWhat, sWithWhat
    End With
End Sub
```

And to test it

```
Sub Test()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
        Call ReplaceText(.TextFrame.TextRange, "text", "newtext")
    End With
End Sub
```